# Dual Boot Setup Into Existing Win-10 Machine

Tags: dual-boot

Re-tried to install version 18.10 into a machine with an existing Win-10 OS after making a partition under Windows and changing the BIOS as noted in answers to a similar question. Using the 'install alongside' prompt again worked only so far until the operation announced 'This computer has no detected operating system'. Cancelled at that point as the choices did not indicate that Win-10 would be preserved.Do I need to use a third party boot manager? Or what else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to ask ubuntu.

I think you're overthinking a bit what it is ubuntu does these days.

lately things have been going much better regarding windows 10 / ubuntu 18 + dual booting, so you should disregard these other questions.

here is the process I used with my brand new windows 10 asus gaming laptop that led to a clean dual boot with grub 1st and boot.ini loaded when you select the "windows 10" option in grub, it works flawlessly and both parties leave the other alone :

1. on windows open up powershell with administrative priveledges
   (that's right click on the icon, "run as Administrator"). type:
   `powercfg -h off`
2. plug in your ubuntu USB key (make sure it is uefi
   mode, rufus is a good tool to make uefi boot keys)
3. then open up
   settings go to "Recovery" and select "Restart Now" under "Advanced Startup"
   [image]