# Installing Windows 10 and Parrot OS - with CloverEFI - after Ubuntu is installed?

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, windows

I am newbie here so please be patience. If this questions is duplicated - please close it and show the right answer and steps here.

The aim is that it should show this when I am starting up:
[Clower Bootloader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik5Q2.png)

So from here I can select Ubuntu, Win10, ParrotOS.

Description: Now Ubuntu is newly installed on this comp. I have the Ubuntu USB stick and the Windows 10 USB stick which are ready to use.

This has now these partitions:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 207F026E-CFF3-4FA3-AA43-45493BA58ED8

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624 976771071 975720448 465,3G Linux LVM
```

The challenge is that install Win10 and Parrot Security after Ubuntu is installed - so somehow solve to do not mess up Grub and replace it to CloverEfi.

One of the method what I find to boot from the UbuntuLiveUSB with the option "Try Ubuntu". From here I can reach Gparted and re-partion the disk to create partion to Win10 and ParrotOS.

This is what I found: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hwk0m_rewA0

The another one is - which one seems me a bit more stable - to setup Win10 so format everything then setup Ubuntu and ParrotOS and disable Grub and install CloverEfi.

**So how to setup CloverEfi with Win10, Ubuntu, ParrotOS?**

Comment: ok, I did understand that you are a newbie, so I will be carfull to be nice :) to better help you I need to ask you another question first: is this ubuntu install just a test, are you ok with saving your files from it to some other place like a usb key/drive, online drive or other fat32/ntfs partition/hard drive and deleting your ubuntu? ...because installing windows **after** ubuntu is something you definitely should **not** attempt. The whole process is very very easy if you install windows first (which will erase your ubuntu from the drive) and then install ubuntu and parrot OS

Comment: You have a LVM install which uses the entire drive. Did you also use encryption? But LVM will not support Windows and do not know if ParrotOS can be installed inside the LVM. And shrinking LVM, is an advanced topic. And tools used for LVM are different than those for standard partitions.

Comment: @tatsu Yep, it is no problem the entire Ubuntu set is now 1-hour old. 
But can I ask this issue's background? Is this because the WinBootloader is not fitting somehow with Grub/Grub2 ?

Comment: @oldfred So LVM is a disk-handling layer or driver or sort of ? I found this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux) 
What does it modificate if I encrypt the disks? ( But without encryption I think ) Is it important?

Comment: So the issue can be solved with the following steps: 

 -Install Windows 10 
 -Format properly for two 50 gb places for the Ubuntu and Linux( Does it matter if I format them fat32/ntfs so the Ubuntu/Parrot installer will delete them and formating for ext4, right? ) 
- Then disable Grub2 and setup Clover

Any idea in this rainny-sunny Saturday? 

Greetings from Hungary! :)

Comment: no don't format from windows 10. at least not for ubuntu, I don't know if parrot OS can do this as well although I don't see why not but : ubuntu can resize the windows partition while it is being installed to make room for itself, ust make sure windows isn't locking the hard drives in read only mode by following this guide : https://askubuntu.com/a/1124782/307184

Comment: Are you using Clover because you have a BIOS system, but want UEFI installs? Or just because you want Clover over grub or rEFInd boot managers?

Comment: @oldfred I just want to use Clover. Now I am still figuring out because something happened with the USB Sticks despite so many attempts I could not setup Windows because it always give an error meanwhile setup or with Bios. 
But from here I can easily create a Ubuntu OS on this comp but first want to reach Windows.

Look I created this question :) 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161356/how-to-create-bootable-usb-when-you-are-currently-using-try-ubuntu

Comment: Ok guys it is working now - Win10 is on the broad.

So now can I simple plug in my Ubuntu and install on one of my partition?

Comment: Oh yep here are my partitions. On the 50GB and 365GB are the Fat32. Also there are now an additional 2GB partion for EFI Bios settings - and there are 2 ex4 file system each has got 30 GB storage - for Ubuntu and Parrot OS. 
So now if I install Ubuntu it does not mess up the WinBootLoader but instead of using GRUB2 - which can be replaced by Clover later, right ?